# Spring Cloud Stream Multi Topic Transaction Management

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to create a PoC application in Java to figure out how to do transaction management in Spring Cloud Stream when using Kafka for message publishing. The use case I'm trying to simulate is a processor that receives a message. It then does some processing and generates two new messages destined to two separate topics. I want to be able to handle publishing both messages as a single transaction. So, if publishing the second message fails I want to roll (not commit) the first message. Does Spring Cloud Stream support such a use case?

I've set the `@Transactional` annotation and I can see a global transaction starting before the message is delivered to the consumer. However, when I try to publish a message via the `MessageChannel.send()` method I can see that a new local transaction is started and completed in the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` class' `handleRequestMessage()` method. Which means that the sending of the message does not participate in the global transaction. So, if there's an exception thrown after the publishing of the first message, the message will not be rolled back. The global transaction gets rolled back but that doesn't do anything really since the first message was already committed.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: txn.
            producer: # these apply to all producers that participate in the transaction
              partition-key-extractor-name: partitionKeyExtractorStrategy
              partition-selector-name: partitionSelectorStrategy
              partition-count: 3
              configuration:
               acks: all
               enable:
                 idempotence: true
               retries: 10
        bindings:
          input-customer-data-change-topic:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                isolation:
                  level: read_committed
              enable-dlq: true
      bindings:
        input-customer-data-change-topic:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: com.fis.customer
          group: com.fis.ec
          consumer:
            partitioned: true
            max-attempts: 1
        output-name-change-topic:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: com.fis.customer.name          
        output-email-change-topic:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: com.fis.customer.email
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(CustomerDataChangeStreams.class)
public class KafkaCloudStreamCustomerDemoApplication
{
   public static void main(final String[] args)
   {
      SpringApplication.run(KafkaCloudStreamCustomerDemoApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

```
public interface CustomerDataChangeStreams
{
   @Input("input-customer-data-change-topic")
   SubscribableChannel inputCustomerDataChange();

   @Output("output-email-change-topic")
   MessageChannel outputEmailDataChange();

   @Output("output-name-change-topic")
   MessageChannel outputNameDataChange();
}
```

```
@Component
public class CustomerDataChangeListener
{
   @Autowired
   private CustomerDataChangeProcessor mService;

   @StreamListener("input-customer-data-change-topic")
   public Message<String> handleCustomerDataChangeMessages(
      @Payload final ImmutableCustomerDetails customerDetails)
   {
      return mService.processMessage(customerDetails);
   }
}
```

```
@Component
public class CustomerDataChangeProcessor
{
   private final CustomerDataChangeStreams mStreams;

   @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output-email-change-topic.destination}")
   private String mEmailChangeTopic;

   @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output-name-change-topic.destination}")
   private String mNameChangeTopic;

   public CustomerDataChangeProcessor(final CustomerDataChangeStreams streams)
   {
      mStreams = streams;
   }

   public void processMessage(final CustomerDetails customerDetails)
   {
      try
      {
         sendNameMessage(customerDetails);
         sendEmailMessage(customerDetails);
      }
      catch (final JSONException ex)
      {
         LOGGER.error("Failed to send messages.", ex);
      }
   }

   public void sendNameMessage(final CustomerDetails customerDetails)
      throws JSONException
   {
      final JSONObject nameChangeDetails = new JSONObject();
      nameChangeDetails.put(KafkaConst.BANK_ID_KEY, customerDetails.bankId());
      nameChangeDetails.put(KafkaConst.CUSTOMER_ID_KEY, customerDetails.customerId());
      nameChangeDetails.put(KafkaConst.FIRST_NAME_KEY, customerDetails.firstName());
      nameChangeDetails.put(KafkaConst.LAST_NAME_KEY, customerDetails.lastName());
      final String action = customerDetails.action();
      nameChangeDetails.put(KafkaConst.ACTION_KEY, action);

      final MessageChannel nameChangeMessageChannel = mStreams.outputNameDataChange();
      emailChangeMessageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(nameChangeDetails.toString())
         .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
         .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, mNameChangeTopic).build());

      if ("fail_name_illegal".equalsIgnoreCase(action))
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Customer name failure!");
      }
   }

   public void sendEmailMessage(final CustomerDetails customerDetails) throws JSONException
   {
      final JSONObject emailChangeDetails = new JSONObject();
      emailChangeDetails.put(KafkaConst.BANK_ID_KEY, customerDetails.bankId());
      emailChangeDetails.put(KafkaConst.CUSTOMER_ID_KEY, customerDetails.customerId());
      emailChangeDetails.put(KafkaConst.EMAIL_ADDRESS_KEY, customerDetails.email());
      final String action = customerDetails.action();
      emailChangeDetails.put(KafkaConst.ACTION_KEY, action);

      final MessageChannel emailChangeMessageChannel = mStreams.outputEmailDataChange();
      emailChangeMessageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(emailChangeDetails.toString())
         .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
         .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, mEmailChangeTopic).build());

      if ("fail_email_illegal".equalsIgnoreCase(action))
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("E-mail address failure!");
      }
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

We are getting closer. The local transaction does not get created anymore. However, the global transaction still gets committed even if there was an exception. From what I can tell the exception does not propagate to the `TransactionTemplate.execute()` method. Therefore, the transaction gets committed. It seems like that the `MessageProducerSupport` class in the `sendMessage()` method "swallows" the exception in the catch clause. If there's an error channel defined then a message is published to it and thus the exception is not rethrown. I tried turning the error channel off (`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.error-channel-enabled = false`) but that doesn't turn it off. So, just for a test I simply set the error channel to null in the debugger to force the exception to be rethrown. That seems to do it. However, the original message keeps getting redelivered to the initial consumer even though I have the `max-attempts` set to 1 for that consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_binder_properties).

> `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix`
>
> Enables transactions in the binder. See transaction.id in the Kafka documentation and Transactions in the spring-kafka documentation. When transactions are enabled, individual producer properties are ignored and all producers use the spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.* properties.
>
> Default null (no transactions)
>
> `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.*`
>
> Global producer properties for producers in a transactional binder. See spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix and Kafka Producer Properties and the general producer properties supported by all binders.
>
> Default: See individual producer properties.

You must configure the shared global producer.

Don't add `@Transactional` - the container will start the transaction and send the offset to the transaction before committing the transaction.

If the listener throws an exception, the transaction is rolled back and the `DefaultAfterRollbackPostProcessor` will re-seek the topics/partitions so that the record will be redelivered.

**EDIT**

There is a bug in the configuration of the binder's transaction manager that causes a new local transaction to be started by the output binding.

To work around it, reconfigure the TM with the following container customizer bean...

```
@Bean
public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<byte[], byte[]>> customizer() {
    return (container, dest, group) -> {
        KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> tm = (KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?>) container.getContainerProperties()
                .getTransactionManager();
        tm.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
    };
}
```

**EDIT2**

You can't use the binder's DLQ support because, from the container's perspective, the delivery was successful. We need to propagate the exception to the container to force a rollback. So, you need to move the dead-lettering to the `AfterRollbackProcessor` instead. Here is my complete test class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class So57379575Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So57379575Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel output;

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println("in:" + in);
        this.output.send(new GenericMessage<>(in.toUpperCase()));
        if (in.equals("two")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail");
        }
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so57379575", topics = "so57379575out")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println("out:" + in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so57379575DLT", topics = "so57379575dlt")
    public void listen3(String in) {
        System.out.println("dlt:" + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so57379575in", "one".getBytes());
            template.send("so57379575in", "two".getBytes());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<byte[], byte[]>> customizer(
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {

        return (container, dest, group) -> {
            // enable transaction synchronization
            KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> tm = (KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?>) container.getContainerProperties()
                    .getTransactionManager();
            tm.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
            // container dead-lettering
            DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<? super byte[], ? super byte[]> afterRollbackProcessor =
                    new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<>(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template,
                            (ex, tp) -> new TopicPartition("so57379575dlt", -1)), 0);
            container.setAfterRollbackProcessor(afterRollbackProcessor);
        };
    }

}
```

and

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers:
    - 10.0.0.8:9092
    - 10.0.0.8:9093
    - 10.0.0.8:9094
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      enable-auto-commit: false
      properties:
        isolation.level: read_committed
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: so57379575in
          group: so57379575in
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 1
        output:
          destination: so57379575out
      kafka:
        binder:
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: so57379575tx.
            producer:
              configuration:
                acks: all
                retries: 10

#logging:
#  level:
#    org.springframework.kafka: trace
#    org.springframework.transaction: trace
```

and

```
in:two
2019-08-07 12:43:33.457 ERROR 36532 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while 
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: fail
...
in:one
dlt:two
out:ONE
```

Comment: Thank you Gary for the response. I removed the @Transactional annotation and updated the application.yaml file for the producer. The first message is still getting committed as soon as it is sent. So the exception thrown after the MessageChannel.send() call does not roll it back.

Comment: Do the consumers on those topics have `isolation=read_committed`? If yes, please post a DEBUG log someplace like a GitHub gist or pastebin etc. I may not be able to look at it until tomorrow, though.

Comment: Yes, the consumers are configured as such. I uploaded the debig log contents to Gist: https://gist.github.com/botPotyo/125957dba37a8da642509c2cddfd2297

Thank you for looking at this!

Comment: That log seems to only have tomcat stuff. But I reproduced the issue; it's a bug - I edited my answer with a work-around.

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post. We are making progress but there are still issues.

Comment: You can't use the binder's DLQ mechanism because, from the container's perspective, the delivery is successful, hence the transaction commits. See my second edit.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much for your help, Gary! I really appreciate it.

Comment: It turns out the transaction synchronization problem was already fixed in spring-integration-kafka 3.1.2 (current version is 3.1.4), but the binder is still using 3.1.0.  That said, you would still need the custom after rollback processor.